# Getting HTTP ERROR 404 with Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am getting below error when trying to access jenkins pipeline url. I tried clearing the browser cache, tried different browsers etc but no luck. the same pipeline url works fine for other users but not for me. any ideas why it throwing 404 error for me? many thanks!

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /job/jenkins/job/test/. Reason:

    Not Found
Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT
```

Comment: you probably havent been given permission to see the resource you are trying to load

Comment: Thanks @avigil - i had my devops team to grant me the resource access and now its working for me

Answer (score 7):

After loging in as an administrator, use the url http://localhost:8080.

It initially takes to the url that says jenkins in it's name, which will not work. The URL you want to access is http://localhost:8080

Also if you have a different port binded you can try to call the url as http://[ip]:[port]/jenkins

Answer (score 2):

If you get such error like it was mentioned above you should access through the URL "http://localhost:8081**/jenkins/**", but not only "http://localhost:8081".
Btw my port is 8081 because of the circumstance that my 8080 port is already used.
Have a good day!

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now I would like to know how to make Jenkins reply on "http://localhost:8080" again, as it was doing before I probably messed something (what?) up while installing my .NET Core 3.1 web service on the ISS of the same machine. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

There can be probably one of these reasons :

1. You do not have the access to the job.
2. You do have access to the job but you are not logged in . Try to login to jenkins in another window and check remember me on this computer , then open that url.
3. You are trying to access it from another server which is not whitelisted from the jenkins master server ,i.e it is not allowed access.

These are the best guesses I coud get .If these do not work then someone needs to manually check the url you are entering and other environment related issues themselves.

Answer (score 0):

There is a common mistake that most of the people making.(while running jenkins.war from CMD)

Please ensure that your tomcat server is 'up and running' locally.

Answer (score 0):

try restarting your jenkins service with $sudo service jenkins restart

Answer (score 0):

When I ran jenkins.war from CMD, I faced the same issue. Practically when you run jenkins.war from CMD, localhost:8080 is where jenkins is available. But if you run the startup.bat file, then the path you have set, say, localhost:8080/jenkins will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a hook this error occurs. This is a known issue in GIT showing 404 error. Way around of the above said problem is to use the NIC ID instead of using "localhost".

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue and identified JIRA and Jenkins are installed on same port 8080. Jenkins service is starting first because of that JIRA was not working. Then I have edited Jenkins.xml file with port 8081 and restarted the services it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I used a docker container to start jenkins locally for a test purpose.
Here is the cmd: `docker run -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 jenkins` reffered to official documentation: https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins?tab=description.

After started the container, I browsed into http://localhost:8080 and got

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /job/jenkins/job/test/. Reason:

    Not Found
Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT
```

I just removed exposing the JNLP port which is `50000`

And the command to start docker was: `docker run -p 8080:8080 jenkins`

And now, I was able to browse the application at http://localhost:8080 without not found error.

Thanks